# <AFrame> How does icon for fullscreen stay at bottom right edge?

Tags: aframe

The icon for fullscreen mode (looks roughly like a set of goggles, maybe at 50% transparent gray and solid white) always sits on the bottom right of the browser screen when viewing via desktop.

The positioning is such that despite potentially disruptive acts such as changing the window size, pressing  to bring up console, or fov changes to the camera angle, the icon's position is fixed.

How is this achieved?

I would like to construct a similar element (rectangle would be fine) and position it somewhere stable (bottom center, perhaps) where it can be clicked by a mouse, when the application is being run in a "desktop" mode rather than viewed through visor or cardboard. The application is displays 360-photos.

---

EDIT: (part of original question deleted for clarity, question expanded to get more details of the proper usage of CSS)

Answer posted by ngokevin suggests using CSS.

I have used CSS successfully with HTML and simple JavaScript situations. Am having trouble with getting it to work in the AFRAME context.

In the below example is one of several tries to alter the "bottom" attribute, but it isn't having an effect. (Tried using id instead of class, using the literal string provided in the answer, using absolute or not, various other things.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS/AFRAME Test</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .plane { position:absolute; bottom: 100px ! important;}  
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-plane class="plane"
       height="1"
       width="3" 
       position="0 0 -4"
       material="color: red">
    </a-plane>    

    <a-camera fov="100" look-controls></a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Changing the value for "bottom" has no effect. Is it possible, for example, to make this rectangle always hug the center bottom edge using CSS?

Would it be possible to show an edit the above so that CSS is used to affect any attribute of the  so I can see and play with a working example?

If the "plane" element needs to be 2D HTML, how do we set to overlap the a-scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just CSS. You can override it (e.g., something like `.a-enter-vr-button { bottom: auto !important; top: 10px; }`)

Comment: Is this done via a <Style> tag in the header? Or setAttribute in JS? Or some other method? I'm thinking that the entity would no longer be a child of the camera in this case, but instead a direct member of <a-scene>, yes? I'm trying out different possibilities but not able to implement your solution yet.

Comment: It's with CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics

Comment: I've added a very short example to the question, trying to get the style tag to work. Hopefully a short answer or quick edit will illuminate the answer you gave. I've gone through just over half of the w3com CSS tutorial recently and have been using it for simpler situations. Mozilla alternative you linked looks useful to read, too, though non-specific. Thanks for that.

Comment: The answer I provided gives the exact class name for styling the icon button in the bottom right hand. What you attempted was to style a completely different element, `<a-plane>`, which won't work because that's not a 2D HTML element. Try to use the answer I provided if you're trying to move that button, else can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I was hoping to learn the technique that is used with .a-enter-vr-button and re-use this with an element that I create (which will trigger a JavaScript function when a mouse click occurs within its bounds--to be active only when users are in desktop mode). The source code for a-enter-vr-button is very hard to disentangle. Are you saying it is a 2D HTML element? How do you overlay a 2D HTML element with an <a-scene>? I will take another look at the source to see if I can find the initial element definition when I get home later tonight.

Comment: Yeah, it's a 2D HTML element. You can right click and view source it. You can just create an HTML element and overlay it with CSS (i.e., `z-index`). Nothing A-Frame specific, just HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post a simple example. Now that I've done it, it seems very obvious, even though it wasn't when I first asked.

The example uses two "p" tags with "fixed" positioning. When the mouse hovers over either tag, a function is called that gets & sets attributes. The Z-Index value is used to ensure that the "P" tags appear above the a-scene.

Because I am new to HTML/CSS I had to do some reading up on positioning. The MDN link on [Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning), and the section on "Practical Positioning Examples" directly after that were very helpful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS/AFRAME Interaction Test</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    p {
      font-size: 24pt;
      text-align: center; 
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      color: white;
      background-color: grey;
      opacity: 0.5;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: -10px;  
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .foo {
      left: 20px;
    }  

    .bar {
      left: 56px;
    }  
  </style>

  <script>
    function recolorPlane() {
      var plane = document.querySelector("#plane");
      var currentColor = plane.getAttribute('material').color;
      if (currentColor == "red") {
        plane.setAttribute('material', {color: 'blue'});
      } else {
        plane.setAttribute('material', {color: 'red'});
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <p class="foo" onmouseover="recolorPlane()">+</p>
  <p class="bar" onmouseover="recolorPlane()">-</p>

  <a-scene>
    <a-sky material="color: #DDF"></a-sky>
    <a-plane id="plane" height="1" width="3" 
        position="0 0 -4" material="color: blue">
    </a-plane>
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```